# How to find current executing line from a hql file

Tags: shell, hadoop, hive, hive-query

I have a sample.hql file which contains below lines.

```
desc db.table1;
desc db.table2;
desc db.table3;
```

I am trying to run it from shell command
I want to find out if a particular column is present in the table or not
For eg-If col_1 is present in table1 the output should say **col1_1 is found in db.table1**

I am not sure how to find it.
I am executing below command

```
hive -f sample.hql | grep -q "<column_name>"
```

But I am not sure how to get the db and table name from each executing line.

Comment: @Ben It will be too time consuming beause for every call I have to access hive shell

Comment: New(er) versions of Hive define ANSI-compliant `information_schema` database that can be queried (from beeline) directly instead of running multiple `describe table`. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1010. So if you've been diligent and kept up with upgrades... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make grep show you before `-B` and after `-A`.  The below command would show you 10 lines before. This likely will get the job done quick and dirty.

```
 hive -f sample.hql | grep -B 10 -q "<column_name>"
```

If you wanted to be a little more careful you might try a for loop instead that feeds the lines to hive one at a time.  If it finds the column it will echo the table it found the column in. ( the '&&' only executes code if the previous command was successful)

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(cat sample.hql); do
    
    hive -e "$i" | grep -q "<column_name>" && echo $i; 
done
```